# printing string-tri using trie.c and trie.h

Tags: c

This is my main file using trie.c and trie.h i made. the purpose of this program is storing the words from dictionary file.

```
node* x = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
x = insert("bb", x);
x = insert("sdf", x);
x = insert("df", x);
x = insert("bbbb", x);
printAllWords(x);
```

.
.
.
.
.

```
        while (fgets(word, MAX_WORD, file) != NULL) {
            if (word[strlen(word)-1] == '\n') { // remove '/n' at the last 
                word[strlen(word)-1]='\0';
            }
            printf("print word : %s \n" , word);
            printf("length : %d \n" , (int) strlen(word));
            dictionary = insert(word, dictionary);
        }
        dictionary = insert("PLEASE", dictionary);
        dictionary = insert("zzz", dictionary);
        printAllWords(dictionary);
```

.
.
.
.

and my output is

```
bbbb
bb
df
sdf
print word : he
length : 2
print word : he's
length : 4
print word : halp
length : 4
print word : hapless
length : 7
print word : hello
length : 5
PLEASE
hello
hello
hello
hello
hello
zzz
```

As you see, my insert method works with pure string such as "zzz" but I don't know why it doesn't work with the words extracted from file....can you please help me?

Comment: My guess is that you are storing the pointer to the string and not copying it in your insert method.  You should store a copy of the string in your trie. That is only a guess as you haven't posted your code. But from your output and the usage, you have stored the pointer to `word` in your loop insert.

Comment: `dictionary = insert(word, dictionary);` --> `dictionary = insert(strdup(word), dictionary);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will guess that your `node` is like:

```
struct
{
    char *word;
    // Left and right pointers, etc
} node;
```

And `insert(char const *newWord)` has:

```
thisNode->word = newWord;
```

If you follow the pointer assignment, all new words in your loop point to the same memory address. The quick and dirty fix is:

```
struct
{
    char word[MAX_WORD_LENGTH];
    // Left and right pointers, etc
} node;
```

And `insert(char const *newWord)` has:

```
strcpy(thisNode->word, newWord);
```

This will store each word in a separate buffer.